# Enjoy someone and enjoy something

Tags: meaning, word-usage, single-word-request

What is the best way to express that you enjoy someone, meaning their company, personality, or time with them? I don't want it to mean a sexual thing inadvertently. Would it be the same or different as enjoying something in particular?

Comment: If you aren't specific, chances are it's misunderstood as some weasel-phrase or an avance. You have to tell **why** you enjoy someone or something. Germans will ask anyway. It's considered polite to be open about your true intentions.

Comment: For me this question is clear, has all context we need, and it should easily be answerable. Answers may be a bit broad but if we restrict it to a few most common phrases we may not get an over-long list here. It certainly is nothing a non-native will be able to answer with a dictionary only. Therefore I believe that this question is a good fit for this site.

Comment: @Janka: exactly this is what makes it hard for a non-native. We should try with an answer, the context given should be specific enough.

Comment: Regardless whether you enjoy the conversation with another person, the workout you have done together or just the company, it is still always a *something* that you enjoy, not a someone. If you say you enjoy(ed) *someone* you would most likely provoke a raised eyebrow or a humorous question about you performing  cannibalism.

Answer (score 1):

In a formal setting the use of *Sie* almost automatically leads to a distance far enough to avoid a misunderstanding as a sexual advance.

> - Ihre Gesellschaft war mir (wie immer) ein großes Vergnügen.
> - Die Zeit mit Ihnen habe ich sehr genossen.

Among friends or with colleagues at work this distance is more delicate to get and we do struggle ourselves at times. It then is always a good idea to keep the enjoyment expressed at a low level and to **be specific**.

> - Die Unterhaltung mit Dir hat mir wieder sehr Spaß gemacht.
> - Ich gehe sehr gerne mit Dir zum Mittagessen.

If we are not specific then all is open and there may be a lot room for (even romantic) speculations:

> - Ich habe Dich sehr gerne.
>     *(probably more romantic than anything else)*
> - Ich mag Deine Art.
>     *(ambiguous, could also mean a deep friendship)*
> - Du bist ein echter Freund.
>     *(clearly not romantic)*
> - Ich schätze Deine Gesellschaft sehr (, aber...).
>     *(too formal among friends, if used then usually followed by **but**...)*

These, of course are only examples. We do have rather wide variations of the theme.